# How to update BLOB data using SQL. I am using oracle 8.1

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, blob

The BLOB data is an XML fragment and looks like this currently in the database

```
    <lrs-conv end-page="34" runhead="LMI v BAULDERSTONE" series="NSWLR" start-page="31" version="1" volume="(2001) 53">
```

I need it to update like below by removing the year in volume.

```
    <lrs-conv end-page="34" runhead="LMI v BAULDERSTONE" series="NSWLR" start-page="31" version="1" volume="53">
```

I have some 1000 records of BLOB data which need to be updated similarly. So I was thinking an UPDATE SQL Script might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below script but it is only making me to update just one record in the database as the parameters of the substr keep changing for other records in the database. I want to change the SQL so that it can update the volume inside the BLOB XML for all records.

```
Update FRAGMENT F
       set F.FRAGMENT_DATA = REPLACE ((select DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(FRAGMENT_DATA) 
           from 
         FRAGMENT where OBJECT_ID = '5037087'
         and fragment_type_id = 77 and doctype_id = 29),
         (select Dbms_lob.substr(FRAGMENT_DATA,7,106) from Fragment  where 
         OBJECT_ID = '5037087'
         and fragment_type_id = 77 and doctype_id = 29),
         '')
         where OBJECT_ID = '5037087'
and fragment_type_id = 77 and doctype_id = 29
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thank you very much. This script gives me an idea of how to update BLOB data using SQL.